# Https post is working on Android emulator but not working in Device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to post the data to a Https URL using the below code . I have checked in
emulator its working fine. But it is not working in Device.  Can
someone please help me out.

```
  public Boolean PostData(String data) throws IOException {
  Boolean response = false;
  TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }
  }};

  // Install the all-trusting trust manager
  try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }


  HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier =
      org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;


  SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
  SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
  socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
  registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));

  // Set verifier
  StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  postDataBuilder.append("data").append("=").append(data);
  byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

  URL postURL = new URL(url);

  HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) postURL.openConnection();
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setUseCaches(false);
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new CustomizedHostnameVerifier());
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));

  // ------------------
  OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
  // --------------------------
  out.write(postData);
  out.close();

  return response;
}

private static class CustomizedHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get the response displayed on that URL after we
post the data.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: So.. why are you constructing a `DefaultHttpClient`? It's not like you are using it.

Comment: Actaully in the previous version I used to post to HTTP url using httpclient . Now server was in https and i made the changes and I just missed to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the INTERNET permission?

You have to add to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

(Internet works fine from the emulator, but if you want to use it on a real device you have to use the permission)

Comment: And you're parsing to a page that is on your computer or on an external server?

Comment: what will be the issue @ArcDare do u have any idea?

Comment: Actually I don't really know, I would have to check it with the debugger but I'm too busy for that. What I think is that, when something works on Emulator but doesn't on real device, it's usually linked with some resource you're trying to use and it's not present. I mean, you know your code works fine because it works on emulator. Now you have to ask yourself: What resources am I using that MAY not be on the device? (I'm familiar with posting info with http, but not with security, so I can't really tell you)